# How can I create a random(seed) function using a custom seed for Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

how do I implement a random **function** based on a custom seed?

I need to create a random generator function/component for jmeter based on a custom seed to be able to exactly reproduce a test run which uses __RandomFunctions(). It should work the same way as built in random functions like __RandomDate() etc but based on an initial random seed.

Looking into the Jmeter source it looks like all built in random functions (__RandomDate etc) use ThreadLocalRandom which don't use a custom seed. I also looked into creating a Plugin but that will not help as I need to use it as a function from various samplers. So which is the best way to instantiate a new Random object with a seed and then call it with random.nextLong from various samplers. It doesn't need to be global, a random object per thread is fine.
How can I do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for that, something like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Random(12345).nextInt(),)}
   ```
2. You can [write your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) implementing the above functionality
3. You can [request an enhancement](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)
4. You can [suggest a contribution](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) to existing Random function to introduce "seed" parameter

Comment: 1. Can't use a groovy function for it as it will instantiate a new object for every call and using the same seed will generate the same random number.
2. AFAIU a plugin cannot be called from another sampler or am I wrong here?
3-4.  Takes probably long time (understandable) so my question was 4. where (class method etc) do we preferably instantiate the new Random so it can be  used  the same way as __RandomDate() etc?

Comment: Dear, I'm not too telepathic in order to guess how you gonna use the generated value. If you want to generate it only once and re-use later on amend the function to look like `${__groovy(new Random(12345).nextInt(),foo)}` and then use `${foo}` where you need to refer the value. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information. It is also possible to store an instance of Random class into JMeter Properties (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) and call it from there where required.

Comment: Sorry I really appreciate your help and sorry for the unclear description. Unfortunately the solution will not solve my problem as I need to instantiate a Random(seed) object for each thread and be able to call it (i.e nextLong) from various samplers. A JDBC SQL example would be: select c1 from t1 where c1 = ${__myRandomFunc()} and next call will generate the next random value based on the same seed. In that way all randomized values will be exactly reproducible. I assume an alternative would be to generate a list of random values and pick one at a time from that list.

Comment: You can add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the beginning of your test and use the following code there: `vars.putObject("random", new Random(12345))`. Call `${__groovy(vars.getObject('random').nextInt(),)}` function wherever you need the "random" value. `vars` stand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more details